# In Bazel, fetching jar from private maven repository fails with 403

Tags: java, maven, build, bazel

I am trying to build a simple java project with Bazel, using rules_jvm_external. Some of the dependencies are kept in a private maven repository. 
My WORKSPACE looks like this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "3.2"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "82262ff4223c5fda6fb7ff8bd63db8131b51b413d26eb49e3131037e79e324af"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    name = "maven_deps",
    artifacts = [
        "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12",
        "mygroup:myartifact:version"
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
        "https://username:password@my.repo.io/artifactory/repo",
    ],
)
```

My BUILD looks like this:

```
java_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = glob([
        "proj/src/main/java/**/*.java"
    ]),
    deps = [
        "@maven_deps//:org_projectlombok_lombok",
        "@maven_deps//:mygroup_myartifact",
    ],
)
```

When i run `bazel build //:mylib` the fetching of mygroup:myartifact:version from the private maven repository fails with http error code 403. I hardcoded the username and password for simplicity. The username used is an email so i encoded it, e.g.: `me%40gmail.com`. 
I am using bazel version 3.1.0. 
Passing the username and password through env vars produced the same error.
Fetching the same jar using curl works great:

```
curl -O 'https://me%40gmail:PASSWORD@my.repo.io/artifactory/repo/mygroup/myartifcat-version.jar'
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, Bazel's `maven_install` from `rules_jvm_external` relies on Coursera [Coursier](https://get-coursier.io/docs/overview)* for fetching dependencies. Where I work at, we rely on a [property file](https://get-coursier.io/docs/other-credentials.html#property-file) containing the credentials at the correct location for your OS.

Try setting this:

```
simple.username=<username>
simple.password=<password>
simple.host=my.repo.io
```

In either `/.config/coursier/credentials.properties` (if you are on Linux) or `~/Library/Preferences/Coursier/credentials.properties` on OS X.

(*) https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/blob/master/docs/api.md mentions Coursier indeed